# Before pushing to a remote git repo, is there a way of getting a list of all the files that would get pushed (without parsing the call to git status)?

Tags: git

I am trying to avoid the need to parse the output of "git status".
Is there a command that will return a list of all the committed files that will get pushed on the next "git push" command?

Comment: Note that `git push` doesn't actually push *files*. It pushes *commits*. You either send an entire commit (which contains *all* the files), or you don't send it at all. The thing to look at is what's *different* in the commit(s) you will send, not what files are in them, because *all* the files are in them.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

```
git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only @{upstream}.. | sort -u
```

---

**Explanation**

`--pretty=format:""` to suppress commit info

`--name-only` asks for the list of files

`@{upstream}` is a construct to describe the remote branch the current one is linked to. It's not a placeholder, it's meant to be written as is.

`@{upstream}..` (mind the `..` which makes it a *range*) means everything on current branch but is unknown to the remote branch.

Of course, it's more useful to have it sorted in case you have many commits modifying the same files. Use `| sort -u` for this purpose.

---

**Final note** : Make it an alias!

```
# pf = Push Files (could be whatever else you prefer)
git config --global alias.pf '!git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only @{upstream}.. | sort -u'

# then just
git pf
```

Comment: that won't give me the list of files without having to parse the output...

Comment: You're absolutely right, When I reread your question I realize I was off-topic with my `git push --dry-run`. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You should try
`git diff --stat --cached origin/<<branch name>>`

Example :
`git diff --stat --cached origin/master`

The `--stat` generates a diffstat.
The `--cached` is to view the changes you staged.

Let me know if this works.